# How to get system date in SQL server regardless of server location

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am connected to SQLServer on network which is in other location. But I am executing the `GetDate` function in same server but in my system which is in different location from SQL server location.

All I need is to get the current system date even if i execute the `GetDate` function in network SQL server.

Comment: So, current date of local machine?

Comment: @shree   yes exactly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getdate() function to get date for my timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086189/getdate-function-to-get-date-for-my-timezone) or possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173408/store-current-datetime-according-to-client-side-timezone-in-sqlserver) Either way the Server will have no knowledge of the client so this isn't possible.

Comment: if server will have no knowledge of my location then is there no way to get local machine date ?

Comment: SQL can't get the client application/connection time. You should perform that check client side.

Comment: If you're in a different time zone then just add or subtract the hours from GETDATE() accordingly

Comment: you can also use GETUTCDATE() if you do not know the server timezone.

Answer (score 0):

GetDate will return the local date/time for the machine where the database is - assuming that the server time is set to local time.
GetUtcDate will return the UTC time (GMT).
The server has no way of knowing what the time is at the calling system. If you need to record that at the SQL Server end, you will have to pass the local time to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late but I, being in Indian Time Zone (GMT +05:30) resolved this as following:

```
DATEADD(HOUR, 5, DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, GETUTCDATE()))
```

GETUTCDATE() always gives you GMT time. Adding hours and minutes of your timezone would help. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in Eastern' Standard Time, so

```sql
SELECT GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' as Local_DateTime
```

The above query gets the local date time.  The view `sys.time_zone_info` may be useful in getting the exact name of your time zone for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30')
```

Comment: This is server date/time - the OP wants the client date/time.

Comment: `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` -- this is server datetime...... `SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30')` -- client datetime. 
 provided he should 'change UTC time accordingly'.. **Please check it will work**