# How can i get client system current datetime from sql instance?

Tags: datetime, timezone, client, getdate

Sql server `getdate()` function fetch server current datetime, how can I get client system current datetime from sql server instance?.

One of our client using one database for multiple companies operating from different time zones, being a huge database with many tables, procedures, functions and the `getdate()` function is used as default value for many area.

Comment: Please check out this previous post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173408/store-current-datetime-according-to-client-side-timezone-in-sqlserver

Comment: Thank you Bobbie i checked it but it didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The SQL Server doesn't know anything about the time where the client that called it is located.

Consider using `getutcdate()` instead.   Use UTC exclusively in your database, then convert between time zones in the application layer.

If you feel you need to convert between time zones in the database itself, you will need a third-party solution, such as my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) package.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Mr. Matt Johnson but I belive there must be a solution for this, I am using Sql server client server application, sql client will be installed in every node.

Comment: It doesn't matter about the client.  There's no concept of a session time zone with SQL Server.  Other databases have that ([Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006728), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html), [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set.html), etc.).  But SQL Server has no such concept.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I found this link: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/290a0085-47a5-48ab-9557-1b59ee269a40/call-getdate-from-linked-server?forum=transactsql

```
declare @rmt_time datetime;
exec('SET ? = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', @rmt_time OUTPUT) at [remote_server];
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as local_time, @rmt_time as rmt_time;
```

Hope this helps.